# A question asked about 4 day ago shows as being asked 11 hours ago on pg. 6 of the list of new questions.

Tags: discussion

I just noticed something which doesn't seem right. As the title says, there is a large difference in time between when the question of [How to find the area of a triangle given its vertices?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3100139/how-to-find-the-area-of-a-triangle-given-its-vertices) was asked and when the Newest Questions page says it was asked. I recall the specific question being asked several days ago, I assume on Feb. 4 as it states, so this appears to be the correct value. Is there any particular reason the list of newest questions might give such a different value?

Actually, I see all other questions on this page that I've checked either show the question has been deleted or that the question was asked on Feb. 4. However, when I opened a new window and went to the same page, I see it's all working properly there. Also, in the original window, when I went back a page, then forward again, all of the results are now also apparently correct. As such, this seems to be an error which occurred only once, with an offset in time in the query being incorrect. Has anybody else noticed anything else like this? I haven't myself. It's likely just some sort of temporary problem, such as a corrupted communication or database query error. However, just in case, I will keep my eyes open to see if it happens again and, if it does, check for any type of commonality or pattern with this initial occurrence.

Note the system requires me to enter at least one tag, so I used "discussion", even though "bug" might be a better choice, but I didn't use it because I haven't shown the problem to be reproducible and don't have any particular evidence it's due to a programming mistake. If there's a better tag for me to have used instead, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I can't be sure, but my guess is this is a browser-cache phenomenon.  Going back in the browser may fail to refresh a page (while going forward might cause a refresh on a site like Math.SE).  The staleness of pages is sometimes helpful in finding an item you remember seeing but lack precise search information.

Comment: @hardmath Thank you for your response. You have a good hypothesis, but I don't think it's correct. For one thing, a well-designed site, which this appears to be, would indicate to the browser to not cache transient pages, like those of the most recent questions, as the values will always change. Also, I'm not completely sure, but I rarely go back to the $6$th page of recent questions, and I don't think I did so on Feb. $5$ at around $6$ a.m. GMT.